# Draw route between three coordinates

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I've created a map where a user can navigate from point A to point B (Using google-maps api) and now I'm stuck with the third point.

So my idea is to create a startpoint (Current location) which will draw a route to point A and from point A to point B. Something like this:

StartLocation - point A - point B.

At them moment I can just draw a route from point a to point b.

```
    private String getRequestUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {
    //Setup the origin
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
    //Setup the destination
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
    //Setup sensor
    String str_sensor = "sensor=false";
    //Setup mode
    String str_mode = "mode=driving";
    //Setup path
    String str_path = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + str_sensor + "&" + str_mode;
    //Setup output
    String output = "json";
    //Setup API key
    String key = "key=MY-API-KEY";
    //URL for the data
    String url =  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + str_path + "&" + key;

    return url;
}
```

So how can I add an additional destination? Is there any other url where we can have 3 or more locations embedded? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android) library. Check example uses

```
 LatLng start = new LatLng(18.015365, -77.499382);
 LatLng waypoint= new LatLng(18.01455, -77.499333);
 LatLng end = new LatLng(18.012590, -77.500659);

 Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
                  .travelMode(Routing.TravelMode.WALKING)
                  .withListener(this)
                  .waypoints(start, waypoint, end)
                  .build();
 routing.execute();


 @Override
 public void onRoutingSuccess(ArrayList<Route> route, int shortestRouteIndex)
 {
       //code to add route to map here. See sample app for more details.
 }
```